# Biztalk getting XML from another website regularly

Tags: biztalk

Is it possible to use Biztalk internal functions to perform the following task, instead of writing a custom program?

Regularly extract XML from another website to the Biztalk receive location and further process by Biztalk.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide more information. Is that your website? How is it providing you the data? RSS?

Comment: From an external website http://demo.xml.weather.gov.hk/V2/bulletins/CurrentWeather2_iso-8859-1.xml

Answer (score 1):

BizTalk Server out of the box does not provide a way to poll http endpoints.

For that, you would use the Scheduled Task Adapter (http://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks. But my Biztalk version (2006R2) does not support scheduled http download. Only the latest version supports. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: The Scheduled Task Adapter 2.0 is compatible with BizTalk Server 2006 R2: Release 2.0: last release in Apr 20 2008 by Greg Forsythe, this adapter works with BizTalk Server 2006 and BizTalk Server 2006 R2. Compiled in .NET Framework 2.0  See: http://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/releases/view/12733

Comment: You can also build your own WCF service to parse some Website and return you valid XML message